# How to load data from a factory service before using in application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-services

This is an ASP.NET MVC app with AngularJS.

When the application loads, we have to call some action method which returns a dictionary of resources, string key string value.

This array/dictionary of resources, needs to be available throughout the application.

How can we wait until these resources are loaded before accessing them within the application?

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("TestCtrl", ['cacheService', function (cacheService) {
    var self = this;
    self.test = function () {
        var value = cacheService.getResourceValue('Err_lbl_UserExist');
    }
}]);

app.factory('cacheService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.resourceDictionary = [];

    obj.loadResourceDictionary = function () {
        var httpConfig = {
            url: "/Cache/GetResourceDictionary",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": 'XMLHttpRequest',
                "__RequestVerificationToken": $("[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val()
            }
        }
        $http(httpConfig)
            .success(function (data) {
                obj.resourceDictionary = data;
            });
    }

    obj.getResourceValue = function (resourceKeyName) {
        if (obj.resourceDictionary.length <= 0) {
            obj.loadResourceDictionary();
        }

        return obj.resourceDictionary[resourceKeyName];
    }
    return obj;
}]);
```

**EDIT w/ Accepted Answer**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("TestCtrl", ['cacheService', function (cacheService) {
    var self = this;
    self.test = function () {
        var value = cacheService.getResourceValue('Err_lbl_UserExist');
    }
}]);

app.factory('cacheService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    var obj = { resourcesLoaded: false };

    obj.loadResourceDictionary = function () {
        obj.resourcesLoaded = false;

        var httpConfig = {
            url: "Cache/GetResourceDictionary",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": 'XMLHttpRequest',
                "__RequestVerificationToken": $("[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val()
            }
        }

        $http(httpConfig).success(function (data) {
            obj.resourceDictionary = data;
            obj.resourcesLoaded = true;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("ResourcesLoaded", null);
        });
    }

    obj.getResourceValue = function (resourceKeyName) {
        if (!obj.resourcesLoaded) {
            obj.loadResourceDictionary();
            $rootScope.$on("ResourcesLoaded", function () {
                return obj.resourceDictionary[resourceKeyName];
            });
        } else {
            return obj.resourceDictionary[resourceKeyName];
        }
    }

    return obj;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use *broadcast* and *on* for that.

So once your keys are loaded you fire an event using *broadcast*

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

you listen for that message wherever you need to using *on* :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

you can store the data in a service, this will make it a singleton and you can reuse it, all you have to do is inject the service in whatever controller you need.